# Create Method for instance of Class

Tags: c#, generics, serializable

I have have a generic class for a dictionary in c#, however I would like to have added functionality for OnBeforeSerialize() for the different instances/types of the dictionary.

I have three types:

```
SerializableDictionary<Guid, RoomData>
SerializableDictionary<Guid, AssetData>
SerializableDictionary<Guid, SegData>
```

I need to add this fuctionality to OnBeforeSerialize to run for each dictionary value:

for RoomData:

```
    public void GuidToString() {
        roomData.guid = guid.ToString();
        roomData.assetGuidList.Clear();
        roomData.assetGuidList=assetGuidList.Select(g => g.ToString()).ToList();
    }
```

For AssetData:

```
public void GuidToString() {
    assetData.guid = guid.ToString();
    assetData.segGuidArray=segGuidArray.Select(g => g.ToString()).ToArray();
    assetData.roomGuid = roomGuid.ToString();
}
```

For SegData:

```
public void GuidToString() {
    segData.guid = guid.ToString();
    if (door != null) {
        segData.returnWallGuid = door.returnWall.guid.ToString();
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that the relevant GuidToString functionality is run with the corresponding types of SerializableDictionary? Thanks y'all

-Rik

Here is the class:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
 {
     [SerializeField]
     private List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>();

     [SerializeField]
     private List<TValue> values = new List<TValue>();

     // save the dictionary to lists
     public void OnBeforeSerialize()
     {
         keys.Clear();
         values.Clear();
         foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in this)
         {
             keys.Add(pair.Key);
             values.Add(pair.Value);
         }
     }

     // load dictionary from lists
     public void OnAfterDeserialize()
     {
         this.Clear();

         if(keys.Count != values.Count)
             throw new System.Exception(string.Format("there are {0} keys and {1} values after deserialization. Make sure that both key and value types are serializable."));

         for(int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
             this.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Constraint `TValue` to implement a interface that provides access to the `GuidToString` function. Then implement that interface in your classes `RoomData, AssetData, ...` and you can call it in the serialization process.

Comment: What serialization(s) are you using?  `[Serializable]` is pretty old.

Comment: What thehennyy said sounds good to me.

Comment: I'm using serializable for unity..  I think it's the only way to save stuff to json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface that has a `GuidToString` method:

```
interface IGuidToStringable {
    void GuidToString();
}
```

Have `RoomData`, `AssetData` and `SegData` all implement the interface.

Constrain `TValue` to be an implementer of `IGuidToStringable`:

```
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver where TValue : IGuidToStringable
```

Now you can call `GuidToString`:

```
 public void OnBeforeSerialize()
 {
     keys.Clear();
     values.Clear();
     foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in this)
     {
         pair.Value.GuidToString();
         keys.Add(pair.Key);
         values.Add(pair.Value);
     }
 }
```

I see that `GuidToString` does not return anything, but its name suggests that it does return a string. Have you considered renaming it?

Comment: @Rik Didn't see the `=` there... my bad.

Comment: Assetguidlist is a list of guids that I need to convert t string to serialize in unity